# Limit to how many downloads?

Tags: orangedox

My company is doing an email blast and I would like to try the basic version of OrangeDox to track how many times a file was downloaded. I saw something about a 50 limit link share.

Does that mean 50 different links?
Or will the file stop allowing users to download after 50 times?
Stop tracking after 50 times?

Answer (score 2):

The 50 link limit is on the number of share links you can create with the Basic (Free) version. There is, however, a limit of 200 views/month (to limit abuse) for each share link with the Basic & Pro plans.  There is no limit of share links or views for the Business plan, also note there's a free 14 day trial :)